# How to by pass value of dropdownlist to event onchange in MVC ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, onchange, html.dropdownlistfor

I try with MVC and i don't know how to by pass value of dropdownlist to event onchange .

```
@Html.DropDownList("cblist_id", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.listproduct, new { size = 5, @class = "form-control", onchange = "GetProduct(" + this.value + ", 123)" })
```

And this is function in script

```
 function GetProduct(productid, categoryid) {
////do something
}
```

I get this error for sample

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP._Page_Areas_Users_Views_Permit_GrandPermit_cshtml' does not contain a definition for 'value' and no extension method 'value' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP._Page_Areas_Users_Views_Permit_GrandPermit_cshtml' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

So ,i think the problem when i try get value of dropdownlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this.value` here refer to the context of server-side C#, you need to bind the `this` of the dropdown list on JavaScript `onchange = "GetProduct(this, 123)"`

```
@Html.DropDownList("cblist_id", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.listproduct, new { size = 5, @class = "form-control", onchange = "GetProduct(this, 123)" })
```

and with your function, `GetProduct` do the following

```
function GetProduct(drp, number){
     $(drp).val() 
     //  or
     drp.value
}
```

and something else to pass the value directly like so

```
@Html.DropDownList("cblist_id", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.listproduct, new { size = 5, @class = "form-control", onchange = "GetProduct(this.value, 123)" })


function GetProduct(selectedValue, number){

}
```

Comment: I got it. i use ```$(drp).val()``` .Thank you so much.